# How do I use a custom variable in an If-Else statement inside an Apache config?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

Here's my code (I've commented out the if-else part as it's not working)

snippets/contents of my config files

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/staff.vhost**

```
Define host_domain "staff"

Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost**

```
    #<If "${host_domain} == 'main'">
    #    ServerAlias stage.myhost.com
    #</If>
    #<Else>
        ServerAlias stage-${host_domain}.myhost.com
    #</Else>
```

${host_domain} can have 3 possible values: main or staff or customer

I have tried these comparisons

- "${host_domain} == 'main'"

  AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost: Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_OP_STR_EQ, expecting '('
- "%{host_domain} == 'main'"

  AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost:
  Cannot parse condition clause: Parse error near '%'
- "'${host_domain}' == 'main'"

  AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/available_vhosts/stage_template.vhost:
  ServerAlias not allowed here

I was using this [page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) as guide. But it's doesn't have any examples when using custom variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's [If-Else](https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4) statements are evaluated at request time, while [Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html) has its own logic. That's why it's likely that If-Else wouldn't work with `ServerAlias` at all, or it would give unexpected results. On the other hand, you state that your  "`${host_domain}` can have 3 possible values". What you are trying to do is overly complicated, and you have several better approaches.

- Use separate `<VirtualHost>` for each *main*, *staff* and *customer*.
- Add all these virtualhost to a single `<VirtualHost>` with every option matching a single `ServerAlias`. Then, you can use If-Else statements inside the `<VirtualHost>` to alter specific configuration based on the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable.
- If there was several similar `<VirtualHost>`s (way more than just three) with just a certain changing parts in the configuration, Apache Module [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html) would have been your choice. As the macros are evaluated when the server starts, building a static configuration out of them, it's more efficient than comparing the variables at request time.

Comment: Can you please give an example (or maybe a link) to bullet point 2? thanks again!